# After Shifting the server code is not working on the new server

Tags: php, server

I am shifting the server to the new one when I am trying to delete or approve the specific data from the table it remove from the table for a while the it reappear again. But the code is working fine on the old server.

[image]

Please suggest anything i cant find anything.

Comment: What error are you getting, Is it possible to add some code

Comment: check database user rights.. and if you are getting success, it means, you have also have an issue in your ajax response...

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We can not possibly tell you what might be going wrong with any code, if we get shown screenshots of the front end only, and no code _at all_. Also, you should tell us what you have done so far to try and debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest.

1. Check your MySQL version of your server.
2. Check your getting row id.
3. Check your id sending code in sweet alert code.